# Why is List not being resolved by visual studio here?

Tags: c#, list, compiler-errors

I'm afraid I'm a little new to C#, so I simply copied some code from his documentation. This is using the MailChimp Amazon Simple Email Service API

```
var api = new SesApi(yourMailChimpKey);
var result = api.SendEmail("Subject for test email",
     "<p>Body of HTML email</p>",
     "Body of plain text email",
     new EmailAddress("Sender name", "sender@nogginbox.co.uk"),
     new List { new EmailAddress("Recipient", "recipient@nogginbox.co.uk") },
     tags: new List { "test" } //Problems are on this line, and the one above it
);
```

The problem is that visual studio (I'm using .net 4.5) doesn't seem to be able to resolve the sections where is says "new List {...}"

Am I missing a library, or is there a newer way to do this that I've missed?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't resolve"? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Specifically: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'List' could not be found

Comment: And: Error 2 Cannot initialize object of type 'List' with a collection initializer

Comment: I'm know how to use lists in general, but this seems like a strange use of List use, and makes me wonder if I'm missing a library or the documentation contains an error

Comment: Could you link to the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that there is no type `List`. There is only the generic `List<T>`, which is most likely what the documentation meant to use. (The non-generic version is `ArrayList`, but you really shouldn't use that.)

This means you need to specify the type of the list in your code:

```
 new List<EmailAddress> { new EmailAddress(…) }
 new List<string> { "test" }
```

(This assumes you have `using System.Collections.Generic;` at the top of your code file.)

Assuming the API accepts any collection, simpler solution might be to use an array:

```
 new[] { new EmailAddress(…) }
 new[] { "test" }
```

Comment: Thanks! API still doesn't work, but the solved the compiling issue

Answer (score 1):

Notice there's a difference between "using System.Collections" to "using System.Collections.Generics". The later requires that you specify the list type, such as "`new List<EmailAddress> { new EmailAddress ... }`"

Comment: If I use System.Collections, it will tell me "unable to resolve symbol List"

If I use System.Collections.Generic.it will tell me: Cannot initialize object of type 'List' with a collection initializer

Comment: @Hg3, you need to specify type for generic class constructed this way... And there is no `List` at all in `System.Collections`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got a couple of issues.

First, you need a `using System.Collections.Generic;` directive at the top of your file, as noted by Moshe.

Then, try putting parentheses after your list declaration, like this example:

```
private void Form1_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    ListParam( new List<string>() { "Item 1", "Item 2" } );
}

private void ListParam( List<string> mylist )
{
    MessageBox.Show( "List count = " + mylist.Count );
}
```

Comment: +1. Note that there is no need to add `()`, the issues was with not specifying the type.

Comment: The parentheses are really not necessary.

Comment: Fascinating. It's been such a habit with me to add the parentheses that I had convinced myself they were required. Thanks for the correction. I'm going to leave it this way rather than edit it so that if someone else comes along they might learn something, like I did.